# How to plot a density graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matrix of size 2000 by 300. When I try to plot a 3D graph using surf, it is very dark because of the amount of points. I tried different colors but it is still very dark. How do I plot the density of the graph instead of the 3D? Also, the original matrix was about 3000 times bigger than this (I had to decimate it to get to 2000x300). Do I need another kind of plot for the original one or does density plot work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mesh instead of surf, here is a sample code:

```
clear; close; clc; 
A = rand(2000,300);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));
mesh(xx,yy,A)
```

Comment: that is a bit better, but I think it was because of the difference between lowest and highest points, so putting it in db scale helped better.